# dlopen/etc doesnt compile. Unresolved symbol

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking

I am exploring the usage of dynamic stuff. So far My program (main.cpp) doesnt want to compile, becouse `dlopen`&Co are "unresolved". I DID include `dlcfn.h`.

I need the answer as soon as possible, becouse I have to go home in 30mins(doing rapidly other stuff also).

The correct error message might be "undefined", but this is not my computer.

Answer (score 4):

You have link problem - link with -ldl

Answer (score 2):

when linking you have to link in libdl using something like

gcc -o [my_target] [my_objects] -ldl